# How to decode received data with NSJSONSerialization as base64EncodedString and convert it to NSData in Swift

Tags: image, swift, nsjsonserialization

We are able to encode an image data as base64EncodedString and send from an iOS device to an other one using NSJSONSerialization.

Besides, We are able to receive the image data as base64EncodedString but we are unable
to convert received base64EncodedString to an image at receiving  iOS device.

We tested if we were received base64EncodedString using following code

```
    let gotInfo = notification.userInfo! as Dictionary
    let receivedData:NSData = gotInfo["data" ] as NSData
    let message = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    let receivedString = message
    let receivedD: AnyObject? = message.objectForKey("Field")
    println ("received2: \(receivedD )")
```

At that point "println" shows base64EncodedString of image but following code gives error "extra argument 'base64EncodedString' incall" and we are unable find why we are having this error.

```
    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: receivedD, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions())
```

Once we are able to convert received data to NSData we hope converting it to an image using

```
    let decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more hours searching and tries, we reached an answer. 
we replaced

```
      let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: receivedD, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions())
```

with

```
      let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: receivedD! as String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions())
```

and here is picture.